# KeyError in dictionary but key exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, dictionary

I am having a problem with a keyerror, I know the key exists but i still get an error. Iam a beginner and i do not quite understand previous code examples of this question

```
from requests import *
coin_url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin'
curr_coin = get(coin_url).json()
keys in curr_coin.keys():
     print(keys)

 PRINT RESULTS:
 'id'
 'symbol'
 'name'
 'asset_platform_id'
 'platforms'
 'description'

 description = curr_coin['description']['en']
```

Then i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\dan_t\anaconda3\envs\dtfinance\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers    \exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\dan_t\anaconda3\envs\dtfinance\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",     line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Desktop\Algo\Django\dtfinance\website\views.py", line 255, in coins
description = curr_coin['description']['en']
KeyError: 'description'
```

I used :

```
curr_coin.get('description')
```

which fixed the problem but then key errors continue for the rest of that dictionary, why can i not access this dictionary like i usually have? Even through it is giving me a keyerror the description data is still output just fine to the django template and code works as it should.

```
context = {
                    'cartItems': cartItems,
                    'coin' : curr_coin,
                    'ohlc' : json.dumps(ohlc_js),
                    'description' : description,
                    'related_news': related_news,
                    'colors' : colors
            }
    return render(request,'crypto/coin.html', context)
```

this code should meet MRE now as it runs perfectly fine in spyder but is giving the keyerror in my django project anaconda prompt only,

Comment: What does `print(type(coins))` show?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code dies at the first line due to undefined symbols.

Comment: maybe you have key with spaces `"description "` and then it will not match with `"description"` and using `print(keys)` will not see it - it would need extra chars to see it `print(f">{keys}<")`

Comment: Print(type(curr_coin)) = dict,  I’m just missed the request URL  will add later

Answer (score 0):

The error was a jquery script that I imported, I thought it was a separate error but when I removed the script the KeyError went away, the script I removed was:

The error was:

```
Internal Server Error: /coins/isInViewport.jquery.js
```

In HTML as:

```
<script src="isInViewport.jquery.js"></script>
```